# 'Merge' two identically sized pandas dataframes to one equal sized dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

If I have a dataframe e.g.

```
 | A | B
---------
 | 1 | 21
---------
 | 3 | -1
```

and

```
 | C | D
---------
 | 15 | 2
---------
 | 7 | 9
```

How do I create a single pandas dataframe:

```
 |        | 
------------------
 | [1,15] | [21,2]
------------------
 | [3,7]  | [-1,9]
```

?

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd

# create the first dataframe
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 3], 'B': [21, -1]})

# create the second dataframe
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'C': [15, 7], 'D': [2, 9]})

# concatenate the dataframes horizontally
df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)

# format the values as lists
df = df.apply(lambda x: [x['A'], x['C']], axis=1).to_frame().join(
     df.apply(lambda x: [x['B'], x['D']], axis=1).to_frame())

# rename the columns
df.columns = ['', '']

# display the final dataframe
print(df)
In this code, we first created the two dataframes df1 and df2 with the given format. Then, we used the concat function with axis=1 to concatenate the dataframes horizontally. Next, we used the apply method to format the values in the dataframe as lists, with each list containing the corresponding values from A and C or B and D. Finally, we joined the two formatted columns to create a single dataframe with two columns, and renamed the columns to remove the empty string column names.
```